# Why two strings with the same characters do not return 0 when compared?

Tags: c#, string, serial-port, compare

Hello Every one I'm trying to compare two strings. str1 is read from a serialPort and str2 is the reference string. Code:

```
string str1 , str2 = "Foo";
serialPort1.Open();
str1 = serialPort1.ReadLine(); //I get "Foo" on the serial port.

if (String.Compare(str1,str2) == 0)
{ 
     //do something
}
```

So the strings have the same value but the code inside of the if statement won't run.
If I change the if statement like this:

```
if (String.Compare(str1,str2) != 0)
{ 
     //do something
}
```

The code will perfectly run! So I can't understand what's wrong here? Is there a problem with the encoding or something?

Comment: Are you sure that the data got from serial port doesn't contain special characters and that you use the good encoding ?

Comment: Try `if(str1.Trim() == str2.Trim())` to verify spacing issues, you can also compare lengths.

Comment: @Graffito: I haven't changed the encoding yet and actually everything is in it's default way.

Comment: @cDima: I tried, It's still not working and I don't understand why would be spaces there? thank you

Comment: Have you checked the str1.Length?  Does it equal 3 for "Foo" like you would expect?

Answer (score 3):

May you display the string content as follow:

```
dump(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str1)) ;
dump(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str2)) ;
dump(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(str1)) ;
dump(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(str2)) ;

private void dump(byte[] bytes)
{ // HexaDecimal display
  console.writeln(BitConverter.ToString(bytes)) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man that was a great hint I appreciate that, I get  "46-6F-6F-0D" for the string coming by the serial port and the hex code for my reference is "46-6F-6F". So what is "0D" hex standing for? That's clearly not a space... What should I do now?

Comment: "0D" is a carriage return. After ReadLine(), do str1=str1.Replace( "\r","") ;

Comment: @J.Doe - don't forget to mark the answer as the accepted answer in case it helped you resolve the problem.

Comment: @Graffito - Yes it works...Thank you! How can this replacement be done by straightly using the hex code instead of the "\r" (Carriage return operator)?

Comment: @ Yakimych: How should I mark this as an answer? I have no idea about that!

Comment: You can use  "\x0D" instead of "\r" (*for CRLF, "\r\n" == "\x0D\x0A"*)

Comment: @J.Doe - you click on the checkmark next to the answer and it becomes green. You can see how it's done in the Help Center: http://stackoverflow.com/tour
More about accepting answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Thanks you guys you both rock!

Answer (score -1):

You can use Equals to do the comparison.

In your case:

```
if(str1.Equals(str2))
{
    //do stuff
}
else
{
    //do other stuff
}
```

Maybe it's best to print the strings and see what the values actually are. Maybe they are indeed different.

Comment: For future reference, you can format your code by adding ` characters before and after e.g.: `code here`, or selecting and pressing Ctrl-K